# Should I self-impose a word limit for a journal article abstract

Tags: publications, abstract

The author guidelines for the Journal of Computational Physics [do not specify a word limit for the abstract](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-computational-physics/0021-9991/guide-for-authors#39000), saying only that it should be 'brief'.  But should I impose a word limit myself?  I have heard that some indexing services can truncate overly-long abstracts, though I've not come across evidence that this is this case.

Comment: If they're not imposing a *specific* limit, why should you? That being said, the goal of an abstract is to be a brief snippet that gets potential readers interested in your work. If someone can't figure out in 30 seconds to a minute what you're trying to do, your abstract is probably too long.

Comment: Besides the potential truncation, the closest answer might be a recent (correlative) study, which found that - in contrast to common advice - a larger abstract coincides with a higher amount of citations: http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004205

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you should limit yourself because the goal of the abstract is to be short.
Now, where to put the limit?

A good idea would be to look at recently published articles in this journal and note their length.

Comment: Good answer.  Could be strengthened by looking at some abstracts and providing a suggested maximum.  Hertz: Additionally: try reading some abstracts on a small netbook.  If it doesn't stay "above the fold" it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract should sell your paper, introduce the family of constructs/theies used and may indicate the key narrative/outcomes. It should end after that so that one needs to read the paper. The better journals usually ask for stricter limits. (Journals of ) Pure sciences probably have editors wanting to allow you to use complete sentences and sensible sentences even in the abstract so skipped the abstract word limit out of politeness..

Comment: Are you saying that one should write the abstract as click bait?